# Two Flask Applications at same time

Tags: python, flask

I need to test two Flask Apps in my browser at the same time. By standard, Flask runs the app in the localhost:5000. So, a good alternative would be changing the address of one of the apps. Is that possible? If so, how to do it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can set the addres and port for your app

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=12345)
```

As long as the port numbers don't clash you can run seperate instances of flask apps on the same computer

Comment: You also have to change the name of the `session` cookie otherwise the two apps will overwrite each other `session` state: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52406954/380038

Comment: I tried doing app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=12345) and changing the session, but still get socket.error: [Errno 48] Address already in use. What else should I try?

Comment: Solution for me was simply to add --port 5001 to flask run (see answer by Grev Li)

Answer (score 6):

Since version 0.11, `flask run` is the recommended method to start a development server. In your case, open a new terminal, then run the same app on different port:

```
$ export FLASK_APP=my_app2  # use "set FLASK_APP=my_app2" on Windows
$ flask run --port 5001
```