# Multiple Python Flask apps on single apache server losing sessions when session.clear is called on one of the apps

Tags: python, apache, session, flask, wsgi

I have a couple of python 3.6 Flask apps running on my apache server using WSGI.

There are 2 different apps running on the same apache server:
`www.example.com/lodge`
`www.example.com/dashboard`

Both apps have a unique `app.secret_key`

The `/dashboard` app is a flask app with its own set of routes:
`/dashboard/login`
`/dashboard/orders`
`/dashboard/staff`
The login route calls `session.clear()` and lets the user enter their login information. A logged in token then gets stored in a session variable.
Both the `/dashboard/orders` and `dashboard/staff` routes have a decorator which checks for the existence of the logged in token in session and redirects to the login route if it does not exists.

The `/lodge`  app is another simple Flask app with its own routes:
`/lodge/welcome`
`/lodge/personal`
`/lodge/review`
`/lodge/confirmation`
The welcome route also calls `session.clear()` and then displays a webform. When the user submits the webform, the `personal` route is called which stores those webform input values into session.

The issue that I am having is if I navigate to `www.example.com/dashboard/login` and login, I can then flick between the staff and orders routes no problems at all, however when I then open a new tab and go to `www.example.com/lodge/welcome` (which then calls `session.clear`) and then reopen the dashboard tab and try to go to the staff or orders route, I get redirected back to the login route as the session has been cleared.

`httpd.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    WSGIScriptAlias /newapp "c:/lodge/lodge.wsgi"
    <Directory "c:/lodge">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias /dashboard "c:/dashboard/dashboard.wsgi"
    <Directory "c:/dashboard">
       Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Side note, this does not happen if I access the dashboard app on `http://example.com/dashboard` and the lodge app on `http://www.example.com/lodge`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering my own question here.

I achieved multiple applications on the same apache server quite easily by changing the app configs for both apps. No virtual enviroments or tinkering with wsgi scripts needed!

Lodge app:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)

app.config.update(
    SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = 'session_lodge',
    SESSION_COOKIE_PATH = '/lodge/'
)
```

Dashboard app:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)

app.config.update(
    SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = 'session_db',
    SESSION_COOKIE_PATH = '/dashboard/'
)
```

---

The answeres by @m-dennis and @burhan-khalid porivded some insight to the problem so thanks for that!
Having multiple sub domains was not an option for me and I encountered the same issue when having both apps run in their own virtual enviroments.

Answer (score 3):

> Side note, this does not happen if I access the dashboard app on http://example.com/dashboard and the lodge app on http://www.example.com/lodge

This is actually the reason why you are seeing this behavior. Cookies are bound to *domains* and not *paths*.

Once you set a cookie at `example.com`, it is valid for all links, paths and URLs for that domain. It is **not** valid for `www.example.com` - this explains why it works if you run one of your apps on a different subdomain.

So what you are seeing is the proper behavior.

Comment: Ah I see. Do you have a reccomendation on how to resolve the problem?

Comment: Well you already solved it by hosting the app on a different sub domain (www.example.com vs. example.com)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use virtual environments. It seems that your flask apps running in one python execution thread. [Here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/deploying/mod_wsgi/#working-with-virtual-environments) you can find, how to run your app(s) in a virtual environment.

Comment: I copied the example form the link you gave and updated my wsgi files to include the three lines from the python 3 example and I changed the `activate_this` variable to point to my py files.
ie: `activate_this = 'c:/lodge/lodge.py'` and `activate_this = 'c:/dashboard/dashboard.py'` , however I now get an error in the wsgi file on startup saying that module `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fnc'` (fnc is a python file in the parent directory of each of the apps which has function defs in it). Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: `activate_this` has to point the `bin/activate_this.py` in your virtual environment. You should use different environments for your apps.